# chrome.runtime.sendMessage callback

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, promise

I create an extension, and I write this:

Login.vue:

```
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    {
      command: 'authorize',
      data: { email: self.login, password: self.password },
    },
    function(res) {
      console.log(res);
      res
        .then(response => {...})
        .catch(error => {...});
    }
  );
```

background.js:

```
....
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, callback) {
  switch (request.command) {
    case "authorize":
      let a = Authorize.run(request.data);
      console.log(a);
      callback(a);
      return true;
...
  }
});
```

authorize.js:

```
...
export default {
  run(data) {
    return axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: server_url + '/webapi/login',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      data: data
    })
  }
}
```

but when I run this method, I get an error: "Error handling response: TypeError: res.then is not a function at eval ...".

In the background, I see that I get promise:

```
Promise {<pending>}
```

but in Login.vue I get an empty object {}

Comment: You can't send a Promise using messaging. The messages are internally JSON-serialized (literally using JSON.stringify). Only simple types like strings, numbers, booleans and arrays/objects of these types are transferred.

Comment: oh you're right

Comment: @wOxxOm if you make a message as an answer, I will gladly mark it as a solution